# alert window not working with angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following code in which I want to display an alert when a button is clicked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app>
<button ng-click="alert('test')">Display Text</button>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $scope.alert = function(variable) {
        alert(variable);
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The console is displaying this as an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`

Comment: are you importing all the scripts correctly?

Comment: I think that `$scope` is only defined inside controllers where the `$scope` is injected, it can't be used as just a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ModelCtrl">
<button ng-click="alert('test')">Display Text</button>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var app = angular.module('App', []);
     app.controller('ModelCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.alert = function(variable) {
            alert(variable);
        };
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```